# Whats the way to show a verb in Japanese slang form, the way English uses astericks to show a verb, such as *cries*?

Tags: slang

for further example on twitter, you would see a post of something that usually goes in the format of:

“omg i just spilt my drink
** dies inside **”

I was wondering if japanese slang/japanese social media has their own local version or its the same as english

Answer (score 3):

I think we use `( )`, as in...

> 夏のボーナス１万円でした(泣)

> 昨日５時に寝て今起きた（笑）

It's also common to omit the parentheses nowadays, as in...

> 夏のボーナス１万円でした泣

> 昨日５時に寝て今起きた笑